# C# Dependency Injection - injecting interface that takes the same interface as a parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I've run into a bit of trouble trying to use dependency injection and need help.

I have a service `IService` that is implemented a few different ways in my application.

```
ServiceA : IService { public ServiceA(IDependencyA A, IDependency B) {...} }
ServiceB : IService { public ServiceB(IDependencyA A, IDependency B) {...} }
ServiceC : IService { public ServiceC(IService serviceA, IService serviceB) {...} }
```

In my `startup.cs` file, I will pick which one to use based on a parameter in my configuration file. Something like this:

```
var service = Configuration["AppConfig:Service:ID"];
switch(service) {
    case "A":
        services.AddTransient<IService, ServiceA>();
    case "B":
        services.AddTransient<IService, ServiceB>();
    case "C":
        // ??
}
```

I am able to create and use service A and service B very easily. I inject their dependencies A and B before hand and they get created just fine. The problem is with the third service. I need to inject the two other services into it. My question is: what is the best to do this?

Is there a way I can create concrete implementations of service A and B but somehow use the injected dependency A and B in their constructor? Do I have to mess around with the interfaces to get this to work? Maybe I have to change the constructor of ServiceC to take in concrete implementations of A & B?

Updated: don't know if it's the best solution, but I ended up doing the following to get it to work.

```
...
case "C":
    services.AddTransient<ServiceA>();
    services.AddTransient<ServiceB>();
    services.AddTransient<IService>(s => 
        new ServiceC(
            s.GetService<ServiceA>(),
            s.GetService<ServiceB>()
    ));
```

Comment: Add more details about service C. If it really needs these 2 concrete implementations, then you should change the constructor. Otherwise it will break Liskov Substitution Principle. Fix switch, there are no breaks, and serviceA is registered 2 times.

Comment: The goal of service C is to use the implementation of service A, but if service A could not provide a correct result, fallback to the result of service B.

Comment: Create a factory pattern for required services, and instantiate them when needed.  Not everything needs to be handles by DI()

Comment: Based on your last comment here the usage of services based on their result, you could achieve this in a cleaner fashion using a concept similar to the [Strategy Pattern](https://adamstorr.azurewebsites.net/blog/aspnetcore-and-the-strategy-pattern). It certainly would be better if you could predict whether or not the result will be successful.

Comment: @mymemesarespiciest you may know what A and B means but everyone else, including the compiler, only sees an `IService` without any idea what that means. If there are two concrete implementations why not pass the same instance? Or two A instances? Or two B instances?

Comment: @mymemesarespiciest if you want failover strategies, take a look at [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly). It offers several configurable retry and failover strategies *and* integrates with HttpClientFactory directly, allowing you to easily specify retries or failovers for API calls. Check [Use IHttpClientFactory to implement resilient HTTP requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) in the ASP.NET Core docs

Comment: @mymemesarespiciest even if you don't use Polly directly you should see how it works, how it solves the same problems you may have

Comment: Add `IServiceB` (implemented by ServiceB) and `IServiceA` (implemented by ServiceA) as well. Then use `(IServiceA serviceA, IServiceB serviceB)`.

Comment: Simply use different names for different services and their interfaces. Remember that having same signature doesn't mean you need to put them under same interface.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative. Introduce another interface, so you can register the both `ServiceC` and it's dependencies at the same time, without any ambiguity or circular references.

```cs
interface IService {}
interface IServiceImpl : IService {}

ServiceA : IServiceImpl { public ServiceA(IDependencyA A, IDependency B) {...} }
ServiceB : IServiceImpl { public ServiceB(IDependencyA A, IDependency B) {...} }
ServiceC : IService { public ServiceC(IEnumerable<IServiceImpl> services) {...} }

services.AddTransient<IServiceImpl, ServiceA>();
services.AddTransient<IServiceImpl, ServiceB>();
services.AddTransient<IService, ServiceC>();
```

Comment: Yes it will. DI will usually inject the first registered type. Note that I changed the constructor of ServiceC to IEnumerable<T> so it will receive all of the service implementations.

Comment: I understand why ServiceC is OK. I need to test setup for ServiceA and ServiceB on my own during this weekend.

Comment: BTW: When testing this, how should I resolve ServiceA and ServiceB in e.g. a controller? By injecting `IServiceImpl`?

Comment: The idea was to keep `IService` as the "public API", and only refer to `IServiceImpl` "internally" as an implementation detail...

Comment: I see that OP solved it by using services.AddTransient<ServiceA>(); services.AddTransient<ServiceB>(); , maybe no point digging further into this for now. Anyway, Now  I do understand the logic behind your answer, +1 for that :-) Thanks for your time Jeremy. BR

Answer (score 0):

There must be a better explanation for having such dependencies.

Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection does not provide named registrations like other IoC containers i.e. Castle.Windsor.

There is a way you can still register ServiceC with instances of A and B

```cs
            services.AddTransient<ServiceA>();
            services.AddTransient<ServiceB>();
            services.AddTransient<IService>(serviceProvider => {
                return new ServiceC((IService)serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(typeof(ServiceA)), (IService)serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(typeof(ServiceB)));
            });
```

Comment: Funny that you post this because it's nearly identical to the solution I just found that ended up working. The only difference is that you don't need cast to IService because those services are already implementing that interface.

Comment: aha nice! Btw. I dont refresh while writing. and "funny" enough you think like that :)
The only reason for casting is `GetRequiredService` does require typecasting